# elasticsearch geopolygon expand/offset/buffer

Tags: elasticsearch, buffer, geospatial, offset

I want to use the elasticsearch geo polygon filter but I also want to be able to add an offset to the polygon. I will be retrieving the polygon from one elasticsearch index, going through a Java application and then in to the elasticsearch filter in another index. Can anyone recommend a Java library, JavaScript library or elasticsearch plugin that could add this offset?